# jitsi meet for flutter crash on build

Tags: flutter, dart, gradle, jitsi-meet

Using the latest jitsi_meet package from here [jitsi_meet](https://pub.dev/packages/jitsi_meet),the package installation was not working so googled a lot and ,

Followed each and every step from here [Android steps](https://github.com/skrafft/react-native-jitsi-meet#android-install)

Finally zeroed in to this error on build ,

> Could not determine the dependencies of task
> ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>
> > Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> > Could not resolve project :react-native-jitsi-meet.
> > Required by:
> > project :app
> > > Project :app declares a dependency from configuration 'implementation' to configuration 'default' which is not declared in
> > the descriptor for project :react-native-jitsi-meet.

Now it looks like node_modules were never generated for jitsi_meet as on further googling this path was not accesible it seems in `settings.gradle`, `../node_modules/react-native-jitsi-meet/android`

```
include ':app'

def flutterProjectRoot = rootProject.projectDir.parentFile.toPath()

def plugins = new Properties()
def pluginsFile = new File(flutterProjectRoot.toFile(), '.flutter-plugins')
if (pluginsFile.exists()) {
    pluginsFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader -> plugins.load(reader) }
}

include ':react-native-jitsi-meet'
project(':react-native-jitsi-meet').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-jitsi-meet/android')


plugins.each { name, path ->
    def pluginDirectory = flutterProjectRoot.resolve(path).resolve('android').toFile()
    include ":$name"
    project(":$name").projectDir = pluginDirectory
}
```

I was wondering how flutter will use npm to generate those modules, should I be installing npm as well in a flutter project ?The official pub site does not elaborate on this .

Comment: I'm confused, your question references flutter, but the tutorial you link is for React Native?

Comment: The pub package is for flutter , documentation there was not working , the second link is for reactive native , but it has some android specific points to note .

Comment: I would recommend you undo any changes you did as a result of the second tutorial, then go back and ask this question again to resolve the errors you were encountering as a result of the initial installation.

As you point out, Flutter/dart doesn't use npm or node_modules. React native does. So the tutorial isn't relevant to your app.

Comment: @DrSatan1 this is initial question i asked to the package author , can yoi have a look ,https://github.com/gunschu/jitsi_meet/issues/251

Comment: So I looked it over a bit, and I will say that that information is already much more useful. However, I don't know how to start solving that problem. Again, I highly recommend you rewrite this question but only include the information you've included in the Github issue, and leave out the part regarding this second tutorial. Sorry I couldn't be more helpful!

Comment: Did you tried the example app? You should also check if anything missing from the installation settings. If you miss out anything, it probably not going to work.